# Problem with parsering for ldf file in python program

Tags: python-3.x, ldf

when i run my program in python i have got that error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DeskX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lark\lexer.py", line 673, in lex
token = self.root_lexer.next_token(lexer_state, parser_state)
File "C:\Users\DeskX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\lark\lexer.py", line 598, in next_token
raise UnexpectedCharacters(lex_state.text, line_ctr.char_pos, line_ctr.line, line_ctr.column,
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal matches ']' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 1

]/*  QGate V4.0.0 16.12.18 01:30:59 MEZ*
^
Expected one of:
* C_INT
* DBLQUOTE
* COLON
* EQUAL
* SEMICOLON
* ESCAPED_STRING
* C_FLOAT
* LBRACE
* LIN_VERSION
* ISO_VERSION
* RBRACE
* COMMA
* PERCENT
* CNAME
* J2602_VERSION

Anybody know what is wrong? Thank you very much.

I am runnig same program, only thing which change is ldf file

Comment: Without seeing the actual code and input text, it's a bit challenging to pinpoint the exact issue. However, based on the error message The parser is expecting one of the listed terminal tokens ('C_INT', 'DBLQUOTE', 'COLON', etc.), but it encountered a ']' character instead

Comment: sorry i tottaly forgot to share it, i will. Thank you very much for your response

Comment: Here is link for python program: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4su075qu8w5ghtd0oytwg/cfcv-customer.zip?rlkey=ulopthje6f5vbuxpc7zqnmjle&dl=0

Comment: i can only say you can check your ldf file or update ldfparser library......if u can provide your ldf file ....i will give a try then